# Using class database connection in other class

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have a class with a connection to a database

```
$db = new db();

class db {

public $server = 'localhost';
public $user = '';
public $passwd = '******';
public $db = '';
public $dbCon;

function __construct() {
    $this->dbCon = mysqli_connect($this->server, $this->user, $this->passwd, $this->db);
}

function __destruct() {
    mysqli_close($this->dbCon);
}

}
```

Now i want to make an other class and using the connection like this:

```
 class Categories (

function GetCategory($cat) {
    $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY $cat";
    $results = mysqli_query($this->dbCon, $myQuery);
    return $results;
}
)
```

How can i use the connection in a other class?
Can somebody help me out whit this?

Comment: Inject an instance of the `db` class into whatever other class you want to use it with.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `$dbCon` in your db class a static variable, so you can access it from category's using `db::$dbcon` as the connection variable. You could also make a static function returning the static `dbcon` variable, usefull tot check if it is actually a link and not null.

This is just one solution of many possibilities, but probably the easiest to implement because it isn't likely you need more connections to a db, so a static is perfect for it.

A static is nothing more then a variable living in the namespace it is defined in, you don't need to initialize the class in order to access it. It's value is shared across all instances of the object, so creating multiple DB class instances allows you tot just return a static if it was set in a previous DB class instance.

```
class db{
  static $link;

  static function connect(){
    if(self::$link = mysqli_connect(....)){
      return self::$link;
    } else {
      die('could not connect to db');
    }
  }

  static function getcon(){
    return isset(self::$link) ? self::$link : self::connect();
  }
}

class Categories{
  function GetCategory($cat){
    $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY $cat";
    return mysqli_query(db::getcon(), $myQuery);
  }
}
```

Comment: So i change  public $dbCon; to static $dbCon;
But how to use it in the class categories?
I  am a newbee with the oop

Comment: Inside that class you can access it as said above by using `db::$dbcon` or call a function `db::getConn()`

Comment: @Roland since I'm on a PC now, I've added some code.

Answer (score -2):

Create an object of the db class in the categories class. Then use that object to query the db accordingly. Also make sure you use a static variable in the db class. SO that the connection variable is created once and will be used all along the application.

Your db class may look like this

```
class db {

public $server = 'localhost';
public $user = '';
public $passwd = '******';
public $db = '';
public static $dbCon;

function __construct() {
    $this->dbCon = mysqli_connect($this->server, $this->user, $this->passwd, $this->db);
}

function __destruct() {
    mysqli_close($this->dbCon);
}

}
```

Your categories class may look like this

```
  class Categories {
      $connection=db::$dbCon;  
      if(!$connection){
          $db=new db();
          $connection=db::$dbCon;
      }

      function GetCategory($cat) {
        $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY $cat";
        $results = mysqli_query($this->connection, $myQuery);
        return $results;
      }
   }
```

Comment: So you are going to connect to a database every time a new object is created?

Comment: Ah. I notice that thanks for the enlightment. I will edit the answe to use a static variable

Comment: What if class `db` hasn't been instantiated/constructed? `$dbCon` will be `null` and `db::__construct` still isn't assigning any static variable ..

Comment: While your example code can work, it is flawed even after your edit for the exact same reason @dbf mentioned. What if the db class has not been initialized yet? Or it is, but after Categories has been created?

Comment: Am I really a Noob?. Thanks for teaching me this little flaw. I have edited my code to use a static variable of a class. It will use this function if the class was instantiated once, Otherwise will create a new instance of the db class  and use the static variable once again. I think this works now. Thanks @Xorifelse and @ Roland

Comment: @shobipp thank us by accepting answers, and upvoting usefull comments & answers ;)

Comment: @ShobiPP You realize that this code contains syntax errors, still?